# Saving data across rotation does not seem to work in my android project

Tags: java, android, rotation

PLESAE NOTE: The solution to my problem is in bold text at the bottom. I accepted Melquiades's answer because he helped me filter out everything that could have been the problem. It turns out, I was the problem, not android or anything else. So if you are looking for the answer, read below.

I'm trying to save the state of a variable as it is before `onPause();` , `onStop();` , `onDestroy();` are called.

The book I am using has me override a method called

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, myIntVaraible);
}
```

the variables you see in the parameter are declared at the beginning of the class

```
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private int myIntVariable;
```

with this method created, the book tells me to  then go the the `onCreate` method and add

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
   myIntVariable = savedIntanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
}
```

But this does not work.
Whenever the activity is destroyed and created, the `myIntVariable` is reset to 0.

What I did to fix this is  I went to my manifest file and 
added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`.

However, I have read that this is not practical and is strongly advised against.

EDIT: As suggested, I am adding my `onCreate();` and `onResume();` methods..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        iterateQuestions();


        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trueBt);
         mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    correctPressed = true;

                    checkForTrue();
                }
            });


        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.falseBt);
         mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    falsePressed = false;
                   checkForFalse();
                }
            });

         mNextButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.nextBt);
          mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
             try{
                 mIndexCounter++;
                 mTextViewQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_question_view);
                 int QuestionToShow = mQuestionBank[mIndexCounter].getQuestion();
                 mTextViewQuestion.setText(QuestionToShow);
             }
             catch(Exception e){
                 iterateQuestions();
             } 
         }
         });


         mTextViewQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_question_view);
         mTextViewQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                 try{
                     mIndexCounter++;
                     mTextViewQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_question_view);
                     int QuestionToShow = mQuestionBank[mIndexCounter].getQuestion();
                     mTextViewQuestion.setText(QuestionToShow);
                 }
                 catch(Exception e){
                     iterateQuestions();
                 } 
             }
         }); 

         mPrevButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prevBtn);
         mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onClick(View v){ 
                 try{
                     mIndexCounter--;
                     mTextViewQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_question_view);
                     int QuestionToShow = mQuestionBank[mIndexCounter].getQuestion();
                     mTextViewQuestion.setText(QuestionToShow);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    iterateQuestionsReverse();
                }       
            }
         });
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG,"onResume()");
    }
```

For all intents and purposes, the variable `mIndexCounter` is the "myIntVariable" I mentioned.

**SOLUTION:** *I was using a book and unfortunately, since I am new to android programming, relied too much on the code written in the book. The authors usually add new code in their book as bold, black text. This time, they failed to do that and I had trouble figuring out why my data was not being saved. It turns out that it was saved all along, I just failed to update the view with the saved data whenever it was retrieved. After adding 3 lines of simple code, my mistake was obvious and the goal I had been trying to accomplish, a success. 
My program displayed a string of text that was dependant on an `int` that was used to retrieve information from the R.java class. After launching the app, when the user presses Next, the data changes because the int is incremented and the String on the view changes. 
This data was to be saved due to the nature of android destroying any unsaved data upon orientation change.
All I had to do was simply add the saved data, an int, the same way I used to display this string/text in the first place. Instead, I foolishly assumed it would do it automatically because the book did not add this code and I relied on it too much.
This was a great learning experience and if anyone ever comes across something like this, feel free to email me if my answer is not clear.*

Comment: are you changing the value of myIntVariable later? assigning to any different value other than zero?

Comment: It will be changed later yes, but for example, the value of myIntVariable might be 4.. then when i rotate the screen, it should continue from 4.

Comment: is your KEY_INDEX is empty String?

Comment: I forgot to include the KEY_INDEX variable in my code and added the TAG variable instead.

But no, the KEY_INDEX = "index; is assigned the string "index" as you can see.

Comment: if possible, you can make your int variable as static. no need to use of onSaveInstanceState() also

Comment: Can't do that, the variable needs to change eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of in onCreate(), restore your variable in onRestoreInstanceState():

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    myIntVariable = savedIntanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
}
```

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) also say:

> Note: Because onSaveInstanceState() is not guaranteed to be called, you should use it only to record the transient state of the activity (the state of the UI)—you should never use it to store persistent data. Instead, you should use onPause() to store persistent data (such as data that should be saved to a database) when the user leaves the activity.

Btw, change your onCreate() signature to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

as in the docs.

Comment: I didn't have `Override` included because typo, but it is there in my code, thank's for the correction though.

I tried using `onRestoreInstanceState();` and that did not work either.

Comment: Please add some log statements (Log.d()) to your onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() to see in logcat if they are called at all.

Comment: I have added `Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");` and `Log.d(TAG, "onPause()");` to all of these methods respectively, and this is what happens when I change the rotation of my phone. 

This is what my activity goes through:

`onPause();`
`onSavedInstanceState();`
`onStop();`
`onDestroy();`
`onCreate();`
`onStart();`
`onRestoreInstanceState();`
`onResume();

and then finally a TAG called `ViewRootImpl` is shown  with text that reads
`sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`
in red text.

Comment: Please update your question with onCreate() and onResume() code.

Comment: Done. Thank you by the way for all you've done thus far.

Comment: You're welcome. What's the code behind iterateQuestions()? Also, you're doing int questionToShow = mQuestionBank[mIndexCouter].getQuestion(); then setText to questionToShow. You do realize that you're displaying an int, not a string, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43264/discussion-between-melquiades-and-elmedin-zelenkic)

Comment: When I assign `mQuestionBank[mIndexCounter].getQuestion();` to `questionToShow`, it assigns an int that is in the `R.java` class in the nested `public static final class string{ }` class, the int represents the question like so ` public static final int question_1=0x7f05000a;`. The string for this is located in `strings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

As stated **[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)**

Comment: Is there an alternative? Because that too, is considered as a last resort.

Furthermore, why doesn't the way I posted work?

Comment: As On rotation it recreates your activity Overrirde Onsaved instances, save them and fetch them from onResume